# Animating A 2D Stylized Cloud Programmatically

Tags: unity, shaders, graphics

- I am tiling the following background cloud image horizontally.
- I would like to give it more character by making the top of the image deform.
- I would preferably like the puffs on top to bulge bigger and shrink.
- I'd also like the puffs to slightly jiggle as they deform.
- Is there a good way that I can accomplish
  this or something similar through code or with a shader?

Thanks for taking the time!
[image]

Comment: You can get a lot of options on deforming meshes and their textures by using shaders, but this question seems quite generic and not sure if anyone can give a precise answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I apologize if I wasn't specific enough. I wasn't really sure what options would be possible, so I left it a bit open. I'll edit it and try to be more specific!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a classic and pretty cheap trick you can use called "indirect texturing".

[image]

The idea is that we'll read from one texture to calculate a new sampling coordinate, then use that calculated sampling coordinate to read from your cloud texture. This lets us distort the image in all sorts of ways.

First though, we need to do a little preparation. Since the cloud peaks just kiss the top edge of the image, a distorted sample near there could easily cross the wrap-over point and start reading from the bottom of the image that's all solid clouds, which won't look good. So we'll shift the clouds down so the peaks run across the middle of the image, and we have a nice buffer of empty sky above / solid cloud below. While I'm at it, I changed the image to black and white - I'm only going to use it as an alpha mask, and fill in the colour in the shader (saves some file size and texture bandwidth, since we only need 8 bits per pixel).

[image: Modified clouds]

We'll also need a tiling noise texture to use as a source for the random-looking but slowly-varying undulations we want - something with some blurry cloudy greyscale values. [I used this example from Filter Forge](https://filterforge.com/filters/1934-bump.html) for a quick test.

I chose R8 texture format for both textures since I only need a single grey channel. The default texture compression can introduce some nasty artifacts for indirect texturing, where what should be smooth gradients turn into jagged stair steps, so check your texture import settings if you see that.

Then we can write a shader something like this:

```
Shader "Unlit/CloudWarble"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Noise ("Noise", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Intensity ("Intensity", Range(0, 1)) = 0.23
        _Color ("Colour", Color) = (0.8471, 0.8667, 0.9412, 1)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent" }
        LOD 100

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ZWrite Off

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            sampler2D _Noise;
            float4 _Noise_ST;

            float _Intensity;

            fixed4 _Color;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // Compensate for difference in scale between noise swatch and colour swatch
                // and control the scale of the effect from an overall sway to jagged jitters
                float2 noiseUV = TRANSFORM_TEX(i.uv, _Noise);

                // Our first sample will vary the x offset.
                float2 p = noiseUV;
                 // Scroll the noise texture vertically over time to animate the effect.
                p.y += 1.1f * _Time.x; 

                // Fetch sample offset from the noise indirect texture.
                float2 shift;
                shift.x = tex2D(_Noise, p).r;

                // Shift our second sample to decorrelate the y from the x.
                p.x += 0.5f;
                // Scroll the other way at a coprime rate, to disguise the temporal pattern.
                p.y = noiseUV.y - 0.7f * _Time.x;  
                
                // Complete the offset, and re-center it (from 0 - 1 to -0.5 - +0.5)
                shift.y = tex2D(_Noise, p).r;
                shift -= 0.5f;

                // Shift our sample coordinate.
                float2 shifted = i.uv + _Intensity * shift;                
                
                // Colour the clouds and take the alpha from the distorted cloud texture.
                fixed4 col = _Color;
                col.a *= tex2D(_MainTex, shifted).r;

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

I set up the material like so:

[image: Material inspector]

Some notes on the magic numbers I chose (just fiddling by eye):

- Main Texture y scale is less than 1, "zooming in" on the texture slightly so the vertical wrap-around line is shifted out of frame by a safety margin, so that our indirect distortion doesn't peek across that edge.
- y offset is slightly above 0 to shift the texture down and scroll the bottom wrap-around line out of frame.
- x scale is y scale times the aspect ratio of the display quad relative to the cloud texture (here my quad is 8x as long as it is wide, while the texture is 4x, so 8/4 = 2, and 2 * 0.7 = 1.4)
- The Noise scale controls how dense the distortion variation is. The exact values depend on how blobby or grainy your noise texture is. For very small scale values, the distortion ends up almost the same everywhere, and you just get a sway back and forth. As you increase the scale, some parts of the clouds move separate from others. At high values, you'll see lumps and jitters along a single arc, so that's usually a sign you want to back down.
- Because the cloud image is 4x as wide as it is tall, but the noise image is usually square, the noise's x scale is one quarter its y scale to compensate.